# Handle circular dependencies in Ember App Kit

Tags: circular-dependency, ember-app-kit

I'm wondering how should I handle circular imports with Ember App Kit.
Consider the following models:

**entity.js :**

```js
import Contact from 'app/models/contact';
import Organization from 'app/models/organization';

var Entity = DS.Model.extend({
   myMethod: function() {
       // I want to use classes <Contact> 
       // and <Organization>
   })
});

export default Entity;
```

**contact.js :**

```js
import Entity from 'app/models/entity';

var Contact = Entity.extend({});

export default Contact;
```

**organization.js :**

```js
import Entity from 'app/models/entity';

var Organzation = Entity.extend({});

export default Organization;
```

In `myMethod()` should I use require('app/models/xxx') rather than import ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problems while migrating my application(s) over to Ember App Kit and I too have no solution.... did you have any luck on this issue?